# React localStorage object properties returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was just playing around with React doing User Authentication by `localStorage`. The code snippet is given below.

```
export const loginUser = userData => dispatch => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/users")
        .then((res)=>{
            res.data.map(user => {
                if(user.email === userData.email){
                    if(user.password === userData.password){
                        const loggedIn = user;
                        console.log(loggedIn)
                        localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", loggedIn);
                        console.log(localStorage.loggedIn.name)
                        dispatch(setCurrentUser(user));
                    }
                }
            })
        })
        .catch((err)=>dispatch({
            type: GET_ERRORS,
            payload: err.data
        }))
}
```

Now take a look at the `console.log` output

[image]

I'm unable to access the user info because it's giving me `undefined` why is this happening? How can I solve this?

Comment: The [getItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) method of the Storage interface, when passed a key name, will return that key's value, or null if the key does not exist, in the given Storage object. You need to use `localStorage.getItem("loggedIn");`

Comment: So I have to pass ```localStore.getItem('name')?```

Comment: Yes, it will let you access value stored in localStorage.

Comment: Tried it, but it's returning ```null```

Comment: Your key name is `loggedIn` not `name`. Try with `loggedIn`.

Comment: Console logging ```localStorage.getItem('loggedIn')``` returns ```[object Object]``` how can I access the key elements from that?

Comment: You have to parse it. Use `JSON.parse()` to convert object from string. But you have to convert to string while storing it in localStorage like `localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", JSON.stringify(loggedIn))`

Comment: Thanks, I got it working that way.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax for getting user name from localstorage is wrong.

```
JSON.parse(localstorage.getItem('loggedIn')).name
```

`localstorage.getItem('loggedIn')` will give you a user object from localstorage but that is in form of a string.

So you need to convert that into an object and for that `JSON.parse` will useful

This will give you the user name

Answer (score 2):

Set the item as,

```
 localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", JSON.stringify(loggedIn));
```

Then you have to pass in this way, So it will access the value of `name` key in `localStorage`.

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem('loggedIn').name);
```

Comment: It's returning ```undefined```

Comment: Try set item as above

Comment: `localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", JSON.stringify(loggedIn));` as this way and try to get.